# Authority Gem rails app needs to restart for every change to be reflected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization

Hi I am currently using the authority app to add permissioning to my rails app. For some reason, I have to restart my app everytime I want my changes in the app/authorizers/ folder to be reflected.

Is this the standard? Why is this happening?

Is there a way around this?

Even a small change like changing the default from true to false requires an app restart for it to register with authory

```
app/authority/application_authorizer.rb

# Other authorizers should subclass this one
class ApplicationAuthorizer < Authority::Authorizer

  # Any class method from Authority::Authorizer that isn't overridden
  # will call its authorizer's default method.
  #
  # @param [Symbol] adjective; example: `:creatable`
  # @param [Object] user - whatever represents the current user in your app
  # @return [Boolean]
  def self.default(adjective, user)
    # 'Whitelist' strategy for security: anything not explicitly allowed is
    # considered forbidden.
    true
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you check `config/environments/development.rb` if you have `config.cache_classes = false`

Comment: yep it is set to false